# Random selection, probabilistic placement

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability

I have two lists, `X` and `Y`, of equal length. I have a third list, `locations`. The values in `X` and `Y` are related to the indexes of the list `locations`. I also have an equation, which is below.

```
def equat(x):
        return np.power(x, -0.0005165876209672664) - 0.9960910063226581
```

Below is the main for loop for my problem.

```
for i, j in zip(X[:10], Y[:10]):
        A = np.random.choice(X, replace = False) # randomly select neuron from neuron A
        L_a = locations.iloc[[A],] # acquire neuron A's location
        L_b = locations.iloc[[j],] # acquire neuron B's location (unchanged from list)
        D_ = pd.DataFrame(scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(L_a, L_b, 'euclidean')) # compute its distance
```

First up, I have lists `X` and `Y`. `A` selects randomly from list `X`. `L_a` then uses the value `A` to obtain the location of this value. `L_b` uses the first value in `Y`, since as mentioned before, list `Y` must remain unchanged throughout. `D_` will then compute the distance between the `L_a` and `L_b`.

Now, this is where I am kinda stuck. What I would like to do is to, first of all make sure that the two points are not the same, and if they are, to go back to `A` and randomly select another value from the list. Secondly, I would like to add the value of `A` that was selected to be added to a list, say `C`, based on a probability which is generated by the use of `equat`. If this match does not happen, then I would like the loop to go back through to `A` and randomly select another value until the value is selected and added to `C`.

Any advice on how to go about this would be greatly received!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need `zip(X[:10], Y[:10])` because you never used `i`. You can just use `for j in Y[:10]`.

Second of all, for your first question (A != j) you can easily replace `A` assignment row with this one :

```
A = j
while A==j :
    A = np.random.choice(X, replace = False) # randomly select neuron from neuron A
```

also you can do this instead (if `X` is a numpy array) :

```
    A = np.random.choice(X[X!=j], replace = False) # randomly select neuron from neuron A
```

And for your last question, you can get a random boolean value with `equat` distribution using this structure :

```
your_p = equat(A)
should_I_put_A_in_C = numpy.random.choice([True,False], p=[your_p,1-your_p])
```

and then use it to decide what you want to do.

Comment: Also if you have same points in locations and you want to don't pick them in same time, you can use unique of locations or check locations values in `while` condition.

Comment: Thanks for this! Super helpful. On top of the lines:

```
your_p = equat(D_)
should_I_put_A_in_C = numpy.random.choice([True, False], p=[your_p, 1-your_p])
```

errors are occurring stating that `p` must be 1 dimensional. Can you tell me the reason as to why this is happening? I have tried hard coding the p values multiple ways which work but cannot understand what to do when I really need to have the `equat(D_)` value and `1-equat(D_)` values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Keebles What is the type of `D_` when you passed it to `equat`? It should be a single variable. If it's an array, the output of `equat` will be an array too. That's it, `your_p` must be a single variable (`0 <= your_p <= 1`) not an array.

Comment: I thought that was the case, I think I was just having issues with actually getting this as a single variable. All running now. Thanks again!